# How can I make the output return True if everything in the criteria is met?

Tags: python, list

So I wrote this code originally for `passwordlength(password)` to find whether these criterias are met or not...

```
def passwordlength(password: str):
    upper = digit = special = False
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and "1234567890" and "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            upper = True
        if char in "1234567890":
            digit = True
        if char in "$#@%!":
            special = True
        if upper and digit and special:
            return True
    return False
```

and now I created a new function to find whether the length of the string is within 6 to 12 characters AND whether each element in the string appears lesser than 3 times or not.. and here it is

```
def passwordOK(password: str):
    if passwordlength(password)== True:
        if len(password) > 6 and len(password) < 12:
            return True
        for char in password:
            if password.count(char) <= 3:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    if passwordlength(password) == False:
        return False
print(passwordOK(password='aaaa1jd4kjfs$jDhfksfd'))
```

When I tried to run this, it didn't work at all.. Can someone please help me find the error and correct me? Thank You:)

Comment: Try replacing the `and`s in the first `if` in the first function to `or`.

Comment: why do you have a max password length?

Comment: if this is for an assignment or testing yourself this is fine, if this is meant to be used as actual validation I would recommend a library like [zxcvbn](https://pypi.org/project/zxcvbn/) for a password strength checker

Comment: @depperm yea its for practice for my upcoming python course :)

Answer (score 3):

The following would resemble some workable logic and code:

```
def passwordlength(password: str):
    upper = digit = special = False
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" :
            upper = True
        elif char in "1234567890":
            digit = True
        elif char in "$#@%!":
            special = True
    return upper and digit and special

def passwordOK(password: str):
    if passwordlength(password):
        if not (6 < len(password) < 12):
            return False  # return False early
        for char in password:
            if password.count(char) > 3:
                return False # again: return False early 
        return True  # only when all chars have been checked, you know it's ok
    return False
```

Of course the naming is still weird. If I were to redo it:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation

def characterclass_check(password: str):
    for char_class in (ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation):
        if not any(c in char_class for c in password):
            return False
    return True

def passwordOK(password: str):
    if not characterclass_check(password):
        return False
    if not (6 < len(password) < 12):
        return False
    return max(Counter(password).values()) <= 3
```

Comment: One could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants to avoid explicitly entering the whole alphabet, could also prevent typos from causing trouble.

Comment: I would recommend not setting an upper password limit, at least mentioning it

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with this code.

First

```
if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and "1234567890" and "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

will be evaluated as

```
if (char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") and ("1234567890") and ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

thus only checking if the character is uppercase, as the other strings will evaluate to `True` simply by having content. The variable name you're setting is `upper`, so I'm not sure why those other strings are there to start with - they're not what you're trying to check against.

Second, you unnecessarily call `passwordlength(password)` twice when the second one could (and should) be an `else`.

Third, you return immediately on checking the password length in `passwordOK`, so if it's between 6 and 12 characters you never check for duplicate characters.

Fourth, when you check for duplicate characters you return as soon as you find one that appears less than 4 times, meaning that "aaaaaabbbbbbcdddddd" would pass. I assume this was not your intention.

Fifth, your `else` on the `for` loop is unnecessary as in your case it will always run if you don't return from within the loop. It's only useful if you have a `break`.

Sixth, you have a function named `passwordlength` that doesn't actually check the length of the password.

I may have missed other issues.